# ionic 5 unit test with popover controller

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ionic5, angular11

I am trying to spy popover present method in my ionic 5 / angular 11 project but getting an error

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

**Here is unit test code**

```
describe('LoginPage', () => {

 let popoverSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Popover', ['create', 'present', 'onDidDismiss', 'dismiss']);
 let popoverCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PopoverController', ['create']);
 popoverCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(function () {
  return popoverSpy;
 });

 beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [LoginPage],
   imports: [
     IonicModule.forRoot(),
     TranslateModule.forChild(),
     ComponentsModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
       loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
     })
   ],
   providers: [{ provide: PopoverController, useValue: popoverCtrlSpy }]
 }).compileComponents()

 it("check popover preset", () => {
  component.openEntitySelection();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  expect(popoverSpy.present).toHaveBeenCalled()
 })

}


private async openEntitySelection() {

 let popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
  component: PopoverPage
 });
 await popover.present();
 popover.onDidDismiss().then((response) => {
  //Handle response
 })

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're not mocking `onDidDismiss` to return a promise. You also need to use `fixture.whenStable` or `waitForAsync` utilities to wait for the promise to be resolved before doing your assertion.

Try this:

```
describe('LoginPage', () => {

 let popoverSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Popover', ['create', 'present', 'onDidDismiss', 'dismiss']);
 // !! -- Add this line -- !!
 // I am mock resolving it to a value of true, you can resolve it to any value
 popOverSpy.onDidDismiss.and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
 // !! --- !!
 let popoverCtrlSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('PopoverController', ['create']);
 popoverCtrlSpy.create.and.callFake(function () {
  return popoverSpy;
 });

 beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
   declarations: [LoginPage],
   imports: [
     IonicModule.forRoot(),
     TranslateModule.forChild(),
     ComponentsModule,
     TranslateModule.forRoot({
       loader: { provide: TranslateLoader, useClass: TranslateFakeLoader }
     })
   ],
   providers: [{ provide: PopoverController, useValue: popoverCtrlSpy }]
 }).compileComponents()

 it("check popover preset", (done) => { // add done to let jasmine know you're done
  component.openEntitySelection();
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // you have to wait at least for one fixture.whenStable I am thinking
  // because we are returning a promise and we have to ensure that the promises
  // have completed before doing our assertion.
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
     expect(popoverSpy.present).toHaveBeenCalled();
     done();
  });
 });
}


private async openEntitySelection() {

 let popover = await this.popoverCtrl.create({
  component: PopoverPage
 });
 await popover.present();
 popover.onDidDismiss().then((response) => {
  //Handle response
 })

}
```

Comment: i am getting: 'Cannot read property 'present' of undefined'. What is "Popover" in the spy?

Comment: You probably have a `.present` in your code and to the left of it, that object is undefined. So most likely you didn't set the `jasmine.createSpyObj` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<OverlayEventDetail>'.
Type 'boolean' has no properties in common with type 'OverlayEventDetail'